# Adding Object to HashSet

Tags: java, performance, set, equals, hashset

I am trying to add an `Object (Exception)` to a `Set`, however it adds every Exception, eventhough some are duplicates.
[debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/raGAz.png)

In my case duplicates are Exceptions which have the same `Detail` message.

How do I properly add the `Exceptions` to the `HashSet` **only** if the `Exception.getDetails()` doesn't already exist?

Is there another approach than a `HashSet`?

Performance is a criteria here, quadratic solutions (`O(n^2)`)are not an option.

Comment: implement correct hashCode() and equals() for your exceptions

Comment: Can you tell us why you are doing this?

Comment: To properly display on the frontend with my `messageFactory`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options:

- override `hashcode` and `equals` in your exception class
- use a `TreeSet` with a custom `Comparator`
- use a `Map<String, Exception>` where the key is the `getDetails()` result (for example, a `HashMap`)

Answer (score 1):

You need to override how the Execptions are compared so it recognises duplicates the way you want.  You can't do this for a HashSet but you can for TreeSet e.g.

```
Set<Exception> exceptions = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Object::toString));
```

This example compares the `toString` which is the exception type and message in most cases.

If you really want to use a HashSet you need to wrap the Exception in a class which implements hashCode and equals the way you want.

If all you care about is the type and message you can store just the toString of each exception

```
final Set<String> exceptions = new HashSet<>();

public void addException(Exception e) {
    exceptions.add(e.toString());
}
```

Comment: Actually, the to string is not enough, since I'll do further processing with it later. But your TreeSet solution with log(n) works like a charm.

Comment: @0x2E5 in that case you might consider assylias' suggestion of using `Map<String, Exception>` which is O(1) per add.

Answer (score 1):

You need to redefine `equals` and `hashCode` methods.

If the `detail` is a `String` you can redefine them as follow

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
   if (!(obj instanceof YourException)) {
     return false;
   } 
   return getDetail().equals(((YourException) obj).getDetail());
}

public int hashCode() {
   return getDetail().hashCode();
}
```

*Consider this code as a base to program. You have to check for null values for example.*

Once redefined equals and hashCode inserting `YourException` in a `TreeSet` is an operation done in **O(log(n))** where n is the size of the set, from [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> This implementation provides **guaranteed log(n) time cost for** the basic operations (**add**, remove and contains).